# What's the conventional way to handle a transaction in Play 2 Scala?

Tags: database, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using JDO for data storage in a Play 2.1 Scala project. Ideally, I'd like each request to have its own transaction, committing when it's finished, and rolling back if something goes wrong.

The best way I can figure out to do this is with Action Composition, where I create my own `Action`-like object that starts the transaction, wraps the block of code in an `Action`, evaluates it and saves the result, commits or rolls back the transaction, and then returns the result.

The only thing that concerns me about this is that my whole project now consists of `DbAction`s instead of regular `Action`s. I'm not sure why this concerns me, except that I think there must be a better place to do this. However, when I check the hooks available in `GlobalSettings`, nothing looks like it would work.

Should I just go with `DbAction` and stop second-guessing myself, or is there a place to hook this behavior in so that I can just use `Action`?

Todd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that there is a best practice for this yet. I look forward to reading other people's answers.

[This page](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaHttpFilters) should show you how to do what you want to do. Basically in Global you either extend WithFilters or override doFilter. You're still just wrapping the Action, but you're doing it from a central place.

Now, whether or not this is a better idea than doing the action compsoition as suggested [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaActionsComposition), I don't know.

Comment: I wish I could check both of these answers, since they both seem like a way to deal with the issue. I wish other people, who had more expertise, would offer their opinions. I guess the advantage of Action Composition is that I could go ahead and provide some standard bits of data that lots of controllers are going to need access to. The advantage of using a filter (which I hadn't seen before) is that it's all behind the scenes and you deal with anything explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

I don't if it is a better alternative, but you could also use [Action Composition](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaActionsComposition) instead of creating a subclass via inheritance.

Basically, you could write something like this:

```
def TransactionalAction(f: Request[AnyContent] => Result): Action[AnyContent] = {
  Action { request =>
    startTransaction
    try {
        f(request)
        commit
    } catch {
        case e: Exception => rollback
    }

  }
}
```

and then use:

```
def index = TransactionalAction { request =>
  val something = someQueriesInDB
  Ok(something)
}
```

Comment: Duh! I meant Action Composition, not extension. It just *feels* like I'm extending `Action`, but I'm really just wrapping it. I'll edit my question to make it clear.

Comment: No, sorry I wasted your time writing that brilliant answer (which I can say, since that's what I meant in the first place). :-)